# Encrypted Home Directory and SSH (Key-Only-Authentication) breaks X11 forwarding

Tags: ssh, x11, sshd, ecryptfs, xforwarding

While installing Ubuntu 16.04 I decided to take the option of encrypting my home directory. I also use ssh key-only authorization, as password logins are disabled for security.

I was able to solve the "not being able to log in because .ssh/authorized_keys" issue using this: https://stephen.rees-carter.net/thought/encrypted-home-directories-ssh-key-authentication. In summary:

```
sudo vim ~/.profile
```

and then entering

```
ecryptfs-mount-private
cd /home/username
```

But now, X11 forwarding over ssh is broken. It appears the MMC (MIT Magic Cookie) .Xauthority file is not making it into the un-encrypted home directory.

Answer (score 2):

My initial thought is to modify ~/.profile to read:

```
cp "$HOME/.Xauthority" /temp/$USERNAME/
ecryptfs-mount-private 
mv /temp/$USERNAME/.Xauthority "$HOME"
```

Where /temp/$USERNAME is a directory that is owned by $USERNAME and has 700 permissions. I am not sure how secure this option is though.

Comment: Aside from the lack of encryption, I don't see any security concerns with that.

Comment: For clarity, I would be tempted to use `/home/$USERNAME.unencrypted/` instead of `/temp/$USERNAME`

Comment: This removes previous authorizations. You want to merge it instead. See [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/726802/87770), which only merges following a successful ecryptfs mount.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this as my `/usr/local/bin/ecryptfs-mount-private`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# eCryptfs helper script that transfers X11 Authority properly after mounting
# Copyright 2016+ by Adam Katz <https://github.com/adamhotep>, GPLv2+

# If you're root or lack the expected ecryptfs area, don't do anything extra
if [ "$(id -u)" = 0 ] || ! [ -d "/home/.ecryptfs/$USER" ]; then
  exec /usr/bin/ecryptfs-mount-private "$@"
  exit $?
fi

if grep -qs "$HOME/.Private $HOME ecryptfs" /proc/mounts; then
  exit # already mounted
fi

xauth="$(base64 $HOME/.Xauthority)"

if /usr/bin/ecryptfs-mount-private "$@"; then
  echo "$xauth" |base64 -d |xauth merge
fi
```

This safely merges your encrypted home's xauth with the unencrypted home's xauth, which contains the authorization added by SSH. This is essential when you're connecting from multiple hosts simultaneously (overwriting the encrypted `~/.Xauthority` would revoke authorizations for sessions created while the encrypted home is mounted).

It uses `base64` to convert binary data to something safe to store in a variable.

Comment: for temporary `.Xauthority` storage one can also use `/dev/shm` or some tmpfs filesystem instead of `/home`, so the file won't touch the disk

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov – `/dev/shm` can be written and read by anybody, so that's no good. I hadn't realized that `/home/.ecryptfs/$HOME` is world-readable as well, which is almost as bad, so I have altered this code not to use a temporary file at all.

Comment: Well, that's even nicer solution!